Partition edges of a graph by paths where each path can only consist of edges sharing the same property
Say I have an undirected graph where each edge is tagged with a list of properties, e.g. one edge may satisfy property A and B, and another only B and C, etc.
The goal is to partition the edges of the graph into the smallest possible number of paths with the additional constraint that a path can only consist of edges consisting sharing a property.
That is, a path could consist of all edges with property A.
I'm not too familiar with the literature - is this a problem that has been studied before? Or is it equivalent to a known problem?
Edit: mention that I want to minimise the total number of paths.

Yeah, should've mentioned - I want to minimise the number of paths!
